TRON Transaction Broadcast Fails with Signature Validation Error
I'm developing a TypeScript application that interacts with the TRON blockchain to sign and broadcast transactions. But broadcasting consistently fails with a signature validation error. The error message indicates that the signature is attributed to a different address than the intended owner, preventing the transaction from being authorized.
error: Transaction broadcast failed: Validate signature error: 000af534da621ef6c6be22ea6e253fa6c43b7f38fb02527d23ccd479548bc80815205918ce88dc6a7ddd4bddc11e3f4e048171ef979a83611b6cd1b1b0ddee171f is signed by TSBPWie7GK8vgCgrEanCVJLU2zWHK55BRJ but it is not contained of permission.

I have reviewed and refined my transaction signing code to ensure all necessary fields are correctly populated. I verified that the owner address derived from the private key matches the intended address. Additionally, I enhanced logging to trace the data flow during the signing and broadcasting process. Despite these efforts, the broadcasted transaction's signature appears to be from an unexpected address, resulting in a permission error. I expect the transaction to be signed by the correct owner address and broadcast successfully without signature validation issues.
code :
import protobuf from 'protobufjs';
import Long from 'long';
import { walletClient, root } from './grpcClient.js';
import { getPrivateKey } from '../services/vault.js';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import bs58 from 'bs58';
import { AbiCoder } from 'ethers';
import secp from 'secp256k1';

const { ecdsaSign, ecdsaRecover } = secp;
const abiCoder = new AbiCoder();

interface TriggerSmartContractParams {
  ownerAddress: string;
  contractAddress: string;
  data: string;
  callValue?: number | string | Long;
  feeLimit: number | string | Long;
}

interface TransactionExtention {
  transaction: any;
  result: { result: boolean; message: string };
}

export async function createSignAndBroadcastTransaction(
  params: TriggerSmartContractParams
): Promise<any> {
  const privateKeyHex = await getPrivateKey();
  const derivedOwnerAddress = deriveAddressFromPrivateKey(privateKeyHex);

  const ownerAddressBytes = addressToBytes(params.ownerAddress);
  const contractAddressBytes = addressToBytes(params.contractAddress);
  const callValue = params.callValue ? Long.fromValue(params.callValue) : Long.ZERO;
  const feeLimit = params.feeLimit ? Long.fromValue(params.feeLimit) : Long.ZERO;

  const triggerContractRequest = {
    owner_address: ownerAddressBytes,
    contract_address: contractAddressBytes,
    data: Buffer.from(params.data, 'hex'),
    call_value: callValue,
    visible: true,
  };

  const transactionExtention: TransactionExtention = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    walletClient.triggerContract(triggerContractRequest, (error, response) => {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      resolve(response);
    });
  });

  const transaction = transactionExtention.transaction;

  transaction.raw_data.fee_limit = feeLimit;
  transaction.raw_data.contract[0].type = 31; // TriggerSmartContract

  const latestBlock: any = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    walletClient.GetNowBlock2({}, (error, response) => {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      resolve(response);
    });
  });

  const blockHeader = latestBlock.block_header.raw_data;
  const blockNumber = blockHeader.number;
  const blockHash = latestBlock.blockID || latestBlock.blockid;

  const refBlockNum = blockNumber & 0xffff;
  const refBlockBytes = Buffer.allocUnsafe(2);
  refBlockBytes.writeUInt16BE(refBlockNum);

  const blockHashBytes = Buffer.from(blockHash, 'hex');
  const refBlockHash = blockHashBytes.slice(8, 16);

  transaction.raw_data.ref_block_num = refBlockNum;
  transaction.raw_data.ref_block_bytes = refBlockBytes;
  transaction.raw_data.ref_block_hash = refBlockHash;

  const signedTransaction = signTransaction(transaction, privateKeyHex);

  const broadcastResult: any = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    walletClient.BroadcastTransaction(signedTransaction, (error, response) => {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      resolve(response);
    });
  });

  return broadcastResult;
}

function signTransaction(transaction: any, privateKeyHex: string): any {
  delete transaction.signature;

  const rawData = transaction.raw_data;
  const TransactionRaw = root.lookupType('protocol.Transaction.raw');
  const message = TransactionRaw.fromObject(rawData);
  const rawDataBuffer = TransactionRaw.encode(message).finish();

  const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(rawDataBuffer).digest();
  const signatureBuffer = signHash(hash, privateKeyHex);

  transaction.signature = [signatureBuffer];
  return transaction;
}

function signHash(hash: Buffer, privateKeyHex: string): Buffer {
  const privateKeyBuffer = Buffer.from(privateKeyHex, 'hex');
  const { signature, recid } = ecdsaSign(Uint8Array.from(hash), Uint8Array.from(privateKeyBuffer));

  const adjustedRecid = recid + 31;
  const signatureWithRecovery = Buffer.concat([
    Buffer.from(signature),
    Buffer.from([adjustedRecid]),
  ]);

  return signatureWithRecovery;
}



I think this isn't a gRPC or TypeScript issue but rather a nuance of your code that's incorrectly signing the transaction. Tags are best used to bring questions to developers' attention rather than define the technologies in a question. Please consider dropping typescript and grpc tags if these aren't the issue.

you are right, thanks for your comment i removed it
